# Unable to run make command in mac terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, makefile, path

I am trying to install "OpenGL" in my MacOS and while doing so I installed "make". In terminal, when I run 'make', the below error appears.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSFont._fFlags
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
make: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
make: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

Due to technical reasons I cannot access app store. Can someone please tell how to resolve the above problem?

Comment: If you have no copy of Xcode and you have not installed the Xcode command line tools you cannot proceed.